# changing adapter name from hebrew to english

Tags: internet, adapter, netsh, hebrew, english

using:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces
```

i get the following outcome:

```
Idx     Met         MTU          State                Name
---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
 16          75        1500  connected     Wifi
  1          75  4294967295  connected     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
  8           3        1500  connected     Ethernet1
  2          25        1500  connected     ‏‏חיבור מקומי* 13
  5           5        1500  connected     Local Area Connection
```

i'm trying to change the hebrew name to english, so i'm using this command:

```
netsh interface set interface name="‏‏חיבור מקומי* 13" newname="Wifi0202"
```

sadly the output I get is:

```
No more data is available.
```

and the name does not change :(

what am i doing wrong? I'm having problems with it because it's in hebrew.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just delete the adapter then allow Windows to create a new one?

Comment: If I delete it, won't windows just create it again in Hebrew? How can I make sure it doesn't happen?

Comment: Your other adapters are in English.

Comment: because i turned them all to english, somehow, turning them all to english worked fine, just this one fails over and over :(